# OneToOne object is empty

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I'm working with the play framework (v2.3.1) and I have 2 model-objects; a User and a Location. They have a one to one relationship which each other. Saving goes as expected, but when I want to retrieve the user from the database, the location is empty.

My classes:

```
@Entity
public class Location extends Model
{
    public static Finder<Long, Location> find = new Finder<Long, Location>(Long.class, Location.class);

    @OneToOne
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    public String name;

    public Location(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return id+":"+name;
    }
}

@Entity
public class User extends Model
{
    public static Finder<Long, User> find = new Finder<Long, User>(Long.class, User.class);

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    @Column(unique = true)
    public String email;

    public String name;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "location_id")
    public Location location;

    public User(String email, String name, Location location)
    {
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public static User getByEmail(String email)
    {
        return find.where().eq("email", email).findUnique();
    }   
}


public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() 
    {
        User user = User.getByEmail("random@mail.com");     
        return ok( user.name + "\t" + user.location );
    }   
}
```

Example output is: `Some Person 2:null`

Location id is received, but the name variable has a null value. How can I get the Location-object to be filled after getting a user?

Comment: How was this solved?  Having the same problem, id is filled, remaining fields are null

Answer (score 0):

From your post i assumed `Location` is the parent entity and `User` is the child entity.

```
@Entity
public class Location extends Model
{
    @Id
    public Long id;

    // Following field won't persist in database, it will fetch the matching user object based on location_id in the user table.
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "location")
    public User user;

    // .............

}
```

The above `mappedBy` will be helpful when you fetch the `location` entity, at the same time you can fetch associated `user` entity.

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model
{
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "location_id")
    // Above annotation will create a new column in the name of location_id in user table, will be the foreign key of id in the Location table.
    public Location location;

    // .............

}
```

You can finally retrieve location name by `user.location.name`

Answer (score 0):

By default, all relations are loaded lasily. That means, that all entity refrences (that are from another table are not loaded by default ( FetchType.LAZY )). So you should specify, that you want to load it eagerly. Like this

```
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
```